# ORA-01857 when executing to_timestamp_tz()

Tags: timezone, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

Why executing this query over `SQLDeveloper` to connect to my database:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('05/22/2016 10:18:01 PDT', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZD') from dual;
```

**I get the following error:**

```
ORA-01857: "not a valid time zone"
01857. 00000 -  "not a valid time zone"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

But, I'm able to execute the query without any error directly from `sqlplus` on the host where the database is located, getting the expected result:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('05/22/201610:18:01PDT','MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SSTZD')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
22-MAY-16 10.18.01.000000000 AM -07:00
```

So, I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something incorrectly. I have read that error could be cause because of multiple `tzabbrev` for a timezone, but this does not explains why on `sqlplus` runs the query correctly, since I can see the multiple `tzabbrev` for different time regions on both host and `SQLDeveloper` (query from `v$timezone_names`).

The real issue is that our application uses this query, so we notice that this issue reproduces sometimes, even if the application is deploy on the same host as the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add 2 new lines to sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf

```
AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=CET
```

and this fix the problem.

**Updated**

> To eliminate the ambiguity of boundary cases when the time switches from Standard Time to Daylight Saving Time, use both the TZR format element and the corresponding TZD format element

To make your query work without changing anything from the JVM configuration, you should provide the timezone region

```
select to_timestamp_tz('05/22/2016 10:18:01 PDT US/Pacific', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZD TZR') from dual;
```

Because you didn't provide the timezone region, it will get the default one. Let's look at the first parameter 'oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion'. This is defined by the jdbc driver as follow:

> CONNECTION_PROPERTY_TIMEZONE_AS_REGION
>
> Use JVM default timezone as specified rather than convert to a GMT offset. Default is true.

So without defining this property, you force your query to use the default timezone region defined by property 'user.timezone'. But actually you haven't set it yet. So the solution is either you set the property 'oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion' to false (and the database current session time zone region will be used) or provide the it implicitly with 'user.timezone' property

Comment: Hi Thanh,

After making the changes you mention it works. Even if I only add the timezoneAsRegion=false works as well. 

Could you explain a little bit further?

Comment: I see from documentation that the variable modified is this: CONNECTION_PROPERTY_TIMEZONE_AS_REGION

If we change this value, will other queries fail? What is the impact of changing this variable? I'm doing research regarding the property, but I wanted to reply fast so the thread does not die.